# Syntax error when using snakemd in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, syntax-error

I am currently using snakemd to create a markdown template.
When I am using it locally, the file is created normally.
In Lambda, I get the following error:
`Syntax error in module: invalid syntax (generator.py, line 604)`

I checked the line and nothing seems to be off.
Anyone ever came across the same problem?

Comment: Is the Python version the same when run locally and when run in AWS Lambda?

Comment: I am using Python 3.7 in Lambda due to a specific module. And 3.10 locally.

Comment: Well, that's one obvious potential cause but you haven't included any source code so we can't say for certain. If you run the code with Python 3.7 locally, do you hit the same issue? What is the code that's triggering a syntax error?

Comment: The source code is from the github repo of the library: https://github.com/TheRenegadeCoder/SnakeMD

Answer (score 1):

Assignment expressions such as the following ([here](https://github.com/TheRenegadeCoder/SnakeMD/blob/main/snakemd/generator.py#L603)) are new in Python 3.8:

```
items := inline_text._text.split(target)
```

Upgrade your [Lambda runtime environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) from Python 3.7.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this syntax?

Comment: If you cannot upgrade from Python 3.7 because of other dependencies then you might need to locally clone snakemd, modify it, and upload that with your Lambda function. Or use an earlier release of snakemd that *is* compatible with Python 3.7.